# 2011 Community Moderator Election

Tags: discussion, moderation, election

The 2011 Community Moderator Election is now underway!

Community moderator elections have three phases:

1. Nomination phase
2. Primary phase
3. Election phase

Most elections take between two and three weeks, but this depends how many candidates there are.

Please visit the official election page at

https://tex.stackexchange.com/election

for more detail, and to participate!

If you have general questions about the election process, or questions for moderator candidates, feel free to ask them here on meta -- just make sure your questions are tagged [election](/questions/tagged/election).

Comment: The election statistics (for us and all the other SO sites) are available from http://se.awio.com/election.html. Useful for seeing how things are done across the network.

Comment: Also, some handy queries for the stats lovers: http://data.stackexchange.com/tex/queries

Comment: Why are there three open positions but five current moderators?  Are two going to stay on, or are we going to only have three in the future?  (Personally I think having only three might make moderation too onerous a task.)

Comment: @Alan: I don't know why specifically three, but I do know that there is no automatic continuation from pro tem moderator to moderator.  Any of us who want the job will have to stand for election along with anyone else.

Answer (score 5):

Is it only for me, or has the election link on the main site vanished?

Comment: No, not just you: vanished for me too.

Comment: Me too.  (Except I just remembered that we're not supposed to leave "Me too" type comments.  Ooops.)

Comment: @Andrew: but it is useful information, as you are the first non-nominee to confirm this (they might have decided that nominees don't need to see the link anymore).

Comment: Me too, me too. Can I have teh codez plz `:-)`

Comment: @Caramdir: Thanks.  Oops, shouldn't say that either.  (But I am a mod, so maybe mods shouldn't see it so Hendrik is the first real data point.  Incidentally, why aren't you nominating yourself, Hendrik?)

Comment: @Andrew: Same as your 2nd reason. As you see, I already spend too much time here, and it's easier without having 1/3 of responsibility. But I'm still struggling with myself.

Comment: @all, just for completeness: The solution of the riddle [can be found here](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/964/election-link-missing-from-the-main-site).